# UITableViewCell is selected only if it is pressed in a certain area

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to create a tableview from which i will use the selected cells. The tableview only contains 3 cells in view. If i tap the first/last cell, it will get selected, but if i'm trying to select the cell in the middle it will not select unless pressed in a certain area which is about half a cm of the whole cell in the bottom or top, depending on how scrolled the content is.

Note that allowsMultipleSelection is true and i have overridden the setSelected method in the cell with this one:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    if self.isSelected {
        checkImage.isHidden = true
        subContentView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8979414105, green: 0.8980956078, blue: 0.8979316354, alpha: 1)
    } else {
        checkImage.isHidden = false
        subContentView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might happen?

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, i solved it. There was a separate view that was covering the tableview exactly in the middle, having the height almost as the height of a cell.